# CloudFunctionsException when calling Firebase Function in Flutter

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to call a Firebase Function from my Flutter project. In my pubspec.yaml file I have imported the functions import: `cloud_functions: ^0.4.0+2`. I have also set up all the firebase configurations as I have a working connection to the firestore database from my app. I then created and deployed a Firebase Function in javascript as follows:

```
exports.addEventToCalendar = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>
const eventData = {
    eventName: request.body.eventName,
    description: request.body.description,
    startTime: request.body.startTime,
    endTime: request.body.endTime
    };
//more code using these variables
}
```

I have successfully deployed this function to Firebase and have successfully ran and tested it in the Google Developer Console with the following JSON data:

```
{
"eventName": "Firebase Event",
"description": "This is a sample description",
"startTime": "2019-07-18T10:00:00",
"endTime": "2019-07-18T14:00:00"
}
```

So I know this function works.

Now when I try to call this on my Flutter App using this method:

```
void _addToCal() async {
  try {
    final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
      functionName: 'addEventToCalendar',
    );
    dynamic resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      "eventName": "Flutter Event",
      "description": "This is a sample description",
      "startTime": "2019-07-15T10:00:00",
      "endTime": "2019-07-15T14:00:00"
    });
  } catch (e, s) {
    print(e);
    print(s);
  }
}
```

I get an Instance of 'CloudFunctionsException' error.

On the Firebase side, I look into the logs of the function and see several errors including: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`.

Thanks for any help as I am new to Firebase and Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the data from your function in this way:

```
const { body } = req;
const eventName = req.query.eventName || body.eventName || (body.data && body.data.eventName);
const description = req.query.description || body.description || (body.data && body.data.description);
const startTime = req.query.startTime || body.startTime || (body.data && body.data.startTime);
const endTime = req.query.endTime || body.endTime || (body.data && body.data.endTime);

const eventData = {
    eventName: eventName,
    description: description,
    startTime: startTime,
    endTime: endTime
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

You're invoking a **callable** function from your Flutter code, but you're declaring a regular HTTPS triggered function in your index.js. **Callable** Cloud Functions are declared as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable):

> ```
> exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
>   // ...
> });
> ```

Comment: When I change it to this, my logs for the function in Firebase say 'Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventName' of undefined'?

Comment: Did you update the Cloud Functions to read its parameters from `data` and `context` as shown in the documentation I linked?

Comment: Thank you @Frank! This is the right answer. There's need to also add a return to the cloud function, as the response object is not available.